# On the application of $\forall\mathbf{I}$ rule

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Trying to prove this statement.

[image]

In this example, $\forall\mathbf{I}$ would have two restrictions:

- *a* must not occur in any undischarged assumption
- *y* must not occur in A(...*c*...*c*...)

As I see it, this application is not against those rules. What's the problem, here ?

Comment: Are you sure the argument is correct?

Comment: I think the argument is not correct. But I’m trying to understand why that application is forbidden.

Comment: You cannot prove it: $\forall y \exists x (x > y)$ versus $\exists x \forall y (x > y)$

Comment: In line 4 you cannot quantify universally $a$ because $a$ is free in an open assumption (i.e. 3)

Comment: My counter-example shows why the restriction on $\forall$I is needed: we have $\exists x (x > n)$ but the suitable $x$ must depend on the choice of $n$. There is no reason that **one** specific $x$ will "fit" for every $n$.

Comment: Thank you, @MauroALLEGRANZA. I have two questions: when you say "a is free in an open assumption" would be equivalent to "a occurs in an undischarged assumption".

Comment: Also, am I not allowed to introduce existential or universal quantifications inside nested proofs ?

Comment: About assumptions: YES.

Comment: About nested proof: the proviso is about $\forall$ quantifier: you can obviously introduce $\exists$ in the case above getting $\exists y \exists x Dxy$.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I cannot see the difference. Why is it allowed in case of the existential quantified and forbidden in case of universal ?

Comment: It is forbidden exactly in order to avoid: $\exists x Px \vdash \forall x Px$ For the existential case, there is no issue : $\exists x Px \vdash Pa \vdash \exists y Py$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this example, $∀\,\sf I$ would have two restrictions:
>
> - $a$ must not occur in any undischarged assumption

But, $a$ does occur within $Dba$, on line 3, and that was *an undischarged assumption* when you tried to use universal introduction on line 4.

Thus that attempt is invalid.

Comment: Thank you, @GrahamKemp. _a_ does occur within $Dba$ but why do you say it is an _undischarged assumption_. It is inside that subproof. I thought the term "undischarged" was used when a subproof was closed and assumptions that were inside it no longer held. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @F.Zer An assumption is **discharged** when the subproof is closed.  It is **undischarged** while the subproof is still active.

Comment: Thank you so much, Graham ! I did not fully understand that concept.

Comment: What about the new information derived by that undischarged assumption (inside the subproof).Do they have any technical term ? 
When the subproof is closed, are they still in effect ?

Comment: @F.Zer Statements, other than the assumption, derived inside the context of a subproof are simply called **statements**. $~$ Well, the very last statement is *sometimes* named the *conclusion*. $~$ They may be described as *contingent* on that context's assumptions, as they are not directly referenceable *from outside* of their context. $~$ Only the subproof itself may be referenced by certain rules of inference (eg *conditional introduction*, *negation introduction*, *et cetera*).

Comment: Thank you, @GrahamKemp. It's very clear, now. When talking about the premises of an argument (main proof), do they count as a **undischarged** assumptions?